# iCloud sharing - "Anyone with the link" requires sign-in

Tags: icloud, sharing

It looks like "*anyone*" cannot simply go and access a shared document from iCloud, because they would need to sign in to an Apple account to access it, which can be a significant inconvenience compared to the benefit of obtaining the file.

Imagine a person who doesn't have an email (yes). Now they would have to create an email account first, then register it with Apple just to see a shared file? This does not fall into the definition of "anyone" in my opinion. I feel so stupid and deceived even trying to make it work.

Also, even users with existing accounts would require to Sign-In, which can be a lot of hassle (possible password recovery, etc, etc).

Did I misinterpret the procedure, and maybe it is in fact possible to share a document without torturing the recipient of signing in just to view the file?